# Detached criteria on composite PK fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a table with 3 columns as primary key. Code and mapping is as follows:

*class for the composite key*

```
public class CIDResultCurrentState implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4346801004559840730L;

    private String mID = "";
    private String sNo = "";
    private String date = "";
    // getters, setters, equals(), hashCode() omitted for brevity 
}
```

*class for the table*

```
public class ResultCurrentState implements IBaseModel, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5707101766665188676L;

    private CIDResultCurrentState ID;
    private byte[] rData;
    private byte[] pData;
    // getters, setters, equals(), hashCode() omitted for brevity 
}
```

*hibernate xml map*

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="org.irvas.amrregina.backend.model.ResultCurrentState" table="RESULT_CURRENT_STATE">

    <composite-id name="ID" class="org.irvas.amrregina.backend.model.CIDResultCurrentState">
        <key-property name="mID" column="M_ID" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <key-property name="sNo" column="S_NO" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <key-property name="date" column="S_DATE" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="rData" column="R_DATA" not-null="false" type="binary"/>
    <property name="pData" column="P_DATA" not-null="false" type="binary"/>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

All of this works fine. Now, what I need is to write DetachedCriteria query to get specific ResultCurrentState object/record. I tried something like this but it doesn't work (I don't know whether to treat this composite ID as nested property or not):

```
//...
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ResultCurrentState.class);
DetachedCriteria criteriaID = criteria.createCriteria("ID");
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("mID", arg.getType().getMID()));
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("sNo", arg.getSN()));
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("date", date));
return (ResultCurrentState)DataAccessUtils.uniqueResult(getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteriaID));
```

If somebody can help me to write proper criteria, I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As for criteria using composite primary key this should be enough:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ResultCurrentState.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ID.mID", arg.getType().getMID()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ID.sNo", arg.getSN()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ID.date", date));
```

Note that `ID` is used as prefix since you have declared the composite key in the POJO using that name, in the class `ResultCurrentState`:

```
private CIDResultCurrentState ID;
```

As for the query execution I think it goes this way (mine is different -- not necessarily better):

```
return (ResultCurrentState)DataAccessUtils.uniqueResult(getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria));
```

Using mine would look like this:

```
List<ResultCurrentState> result = DataAccessUtils.find(criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria criteria = session.forClass(ResultCurrentState.class);
DetachedCriteria criteriaID = DetachedCriteria.forClass(CIDResultCurrentState.class);
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("mID", arg.getType().getMID()));
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("sNo", arg.getSN()));
criteriaID.add(Restrictions.eq("date", date));
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("ID", criteriaID));
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either... Also, as I already said, I need DetachedCriteria because I'm working with Spring's HibernateTemplate, I don't use Session or Criteria at all.